# ADFS 4.0 (2016) OpenID Connect userinfo endpoint returns 401 when provided with access token

Tags: adfs, openid-connect, userinfo

Any ideas why this is. I have configured a Server Application and a Web API and an ID Token, Access Token & Refresh token is issued. However calling the userinfo endpoint return a 401 with the following header message:

WWW-Authenticate →Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="MSIS9920: Received invalid UserInfo request. The access token in request is not valid."

The access token is valid according to http://jwt.io

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6IjVVbEw5a1JocDJNLUVzTDlBRDJOQ055aHZtdyJ9.eyJhdWQiOiJ1cm46bWljcm9zb2Z0OnVzZXJpbmZvIiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cDovL3Rlc3Rsb2dpbi51bm9wcy5vcmcvYWRmcy9zZXJ2aWNlcy90cnVzdCIsImlhdCI6MTQ4NjYyOTUxOSwiZXhwIjoxNDg2NjMzMTE5LCJhcHB0eXBlIjoiQ29uZmlkZW50aWFsIiwiYXBwaWQiOiJrbnVkIiwiYXV0aG1ldGhvZCI6InVybjpvYXNpczpuYW1lczp0YzpTQU1MOjIuMDphYzpjbGFzc2VzOlBhc3N3b3JkUHJvdGVjdGVkVHJhbnNwb3J0IiwiYXV0aF90aW1lIjoiMjAxNy0wMi0wOVQwODozMjo1Ny4xNDZaIiwidmVyIjoiMS4wIiwic2NwIjoib3BlbmlkIiwic3ViIjoiM2krUGlyRncwSVlkdDVzTVNKQlpKbjVOTXZVWXZVdyt2WHI2Ujd1N0dBZz0ifQ.ajKtSk0xQE1crJkIA-lMLBZj2DtYE6xQo-Stmevh4pOGX17GEePbAFP-g6qPUwtGT_whVj74wRpSlyTBscp2JDsp_CW2E6BsTUI810S6jYRVjkYGxL1QcL1KoKJ8wyYKcxsCeOY2IUKNPnJOxV53Rs8E9EvJgjcsjTJHQw5Z_zC43dsTfCZvVfGrwJ3nn6BGxhIE_bEXvrWdgmg49V7-KK2kVDbDwJGr1iLpqU88-bkHdjGCIuc8XKX5pobWWlcyBmR_dpACM6Tu-d8jYJ_8mbof-eZrqn8YS61rgvRAhAAONyDklWcPgiYnhcMQVHZoCME-rVTjI6LDDY2czhL0rg
```

Answer (score 3):

This question is asked long time ago but let me share my experience.
if you want to execute ADFS 4.0 userInfo endpoint(win server 2016) in a hope to get User profile but what i experienced is it return only Sub attribute 
ex:

```
{
    "sub": "MpR57wSIQz1kiR2uUMrkCQadbgDoztWmMV863Dugdso="
}
```

for anyone to try UserInfo endpoint you need to modify your application group, add api with Identitfier https://adfs.example.com/adfs/userinfo & at Client permission tab tick openId.

for execution of userinfo

Ex:

```
curl -X GET \
  https://adfs.example.com/adfs/userinfo \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN
```

**Note:** In your Acquire Accesstoken code  you need to pass your resource = urn:microsoft:userinfo

> The ADFS userinfo endpoint always returns the subject claim as
>   specified in the OpenID standards. AD FS does not provide additional
>   claims requested via the UserInfo endpoint. If you need additional
>   claims in ID token, refer to Custom ID Tokens in AD FS.

Answer (score 0):

I've only done this once so I don't have much suggestions to make yet. So I cant make any suggested unless there is more detail.

You should try and get more evidence from the AD FS side. Enable debug logs using

```
wevtutil sl "ad fs tracing/debug" /l:5 /e:true
```

Do the repro and then disable logs as follows.

```
wevtutil sl "ad fs tracing/debug" /e:false
```

Then export the logs to view using

```
wevtutil epl "ad fs tracing/debug" c:\temp\userinfoerr.evtx
```

Open that event log in event viewer and have look and see what other errors are reported around validating the JWT.