# ADFS WebProvider returns 401 for UserInfo endpoint

Tags: openiddict

After integrating the WebProvider for ActiveDirectoryFederationServices from preview 4.1.0-preview-1.23108.18, a 401 occurs after the frontchannel redirect and userinfo call.

Probably this is due to the behavior described here: [ADFS 4.0 (2016) OpenID Connect userinfo endpoint returns 401 when provided with access token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42131776/adfs-4-0-2016-openid-connect-userinfo-endpoint-returns-401-when-provided-with).

Apparently the attachment of the resource = urn:microsoft:userinfo is missing.

> In my experience when trying to hit the ADFS OIDC userinfo endpoint you need to pass a querystring key value pair (resource=urn:microsoft:userinfo)

The retrieval and validation of the token was successful.

```
The token response returned by https://[redacted]/adfs/oauth2/token/ was successfully extracted: {
    "access_token": "[redacted]",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "expires_in": 3600,
    "resource": "8f238a5c-2dea-42cd-80eb-abf7638fcadd",
    "refresh_token": "[redacted]",
    "refresh_token_expires_in": 26751,
    "scope": "openid",
    "id_token": "[redacted]"
  }.
```

Is there any way to set the resource or disable the retrieval of user info?

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed in OpenIddict 4.7.0: the userinfo endpoint is no longer used for ADFS.